# syntax highlights in org-mode html export

Tags: org-mode

my question might be very simple, but I did'nt find any answer available on the web.

How to pygmentize code blocks in org-mode HTML export ? I have some code blocks like this :

```
#+BEGIN_SRC puppet
file{'/etc/motd':
  ensure  => present,
  content => 'Bienvenue !',
}
#+END_SRC
```

The exported html is not highlighted, however pygments is able to colorize puppet code.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that you need the htmlize.el package installed. Then, it works out of the box.
htmlize.el is available in MELPA for instance.